# Navigator with html doesn't work javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code and when i press the link with a element i want to hide the ul with class name tab and show the ul with class tab-1 without hidding the both of ul elements.I have tried with jquery but with no success. The jQuery code is the following. 
`$("a").click(function() {`
 `$(".tab").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, "slow");` 
 `$(".tab-1").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, "slow");`
`});` 
How can i do it?

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="tab-1">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: If both ul are nested like they are right now, it wont work

Comment: I don't understand.  If you hide the parent (tab) it will hide the children (which includes tab-1).  So you have to pull tab-1 outside tab to hide them independently. You could still use css to make tab-1 appear in the same "location" when rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show a child of an element that is set to `display:none`. If parent is not displayed...anything inside parent can't be either

However you can set `visibility:hidden` on parent and `visibility:visible` on descendants

```
.tab   {visibility:hidden}
.tab-1 {visibility:visible}
```

Note that this is very uncommon practice. It would help to have a better description of what you want to acheive

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8p1Lrsb0/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just hide all elements that match `.tab > li > a`.

Demo :

```css
.tab, .tab ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.tab > li > a {
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="tab-1">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```